# GLMMadaptive in binomial repeated data

Tags: r, categorical-data, mixed-models

I am doing repeated binomial data with GLMMadaptive in R. Outcomes were collected at 3 different time points(collected at baseline, 12 weeks, 24 weeks)and data looks like:

original data set[image: 1]

I want to calculate the marginal probability of this outcome, and I have missing data (MAR). So I run this model. My model is: fixed effect(time*Treatment+Duration), Random effect only has random intercept.

```r
fm <- mixed_model(fixed = Outcome ~ Time * Treatment + Duration,
                  random = ~ 1 | ID,
                  data = data2,
                  family = binomial(),
                  nAGQ = 15,
                  iter_EM=0,
                  max_coef_value = 50,
                  initial_values = list(betas = rep(0, 5)),
                  na.action=na.exclude)
```

There is a warning by doing this:

```r
> Hessian matrix at convergence is not positive value: unstable solution.
```

And then I use `summary(fm)`, which showed `NAs` in my SE and P-value.

Is anyone know how to fix it? I have been stuck for more than 1 month.......

Comment: Is that your full data set? If so, it looks like you are over-fitting. If not, could you please post the data in reproducible format (eg `dput(data2)`) so that we can debug? We obviously can't do this with a screenshot of your data.

Comment: @AllanCameron, Thank you for your reply. but my data is too large, 228 in total. dput may not be a proper way. Is there any way I can share my data with you. I am quite burned out.......